# Why do we use parent() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

So I'm learning jQuery and encounter a function called parent() that allows you to access the parent of whichever element you've selected. So my question is why this function is there when we can select the parent element directly.

Comment: What do you mean select it directly? parent (or my favourite, closest) is very useful

Comment: You wouldn't do `$("#mydiv > button").parent()`, it's not for that.

Comment: jQuery itself is written in vanilla JavaScript so you can certainly do by yourself everything that the library does. That isn't the point. When then library was first released we didn't have cross-browser mechanisms to do pretty simple stuff such as attaching event handlers or issuing AJAX calls. Even `document.querySelector()` exists because of jQuery's influence.

Answer (score 5):

For at least three reasons:

1. Because of the set-based nature of jQuery. `parent()` returns a *set* of the parent elements of the elements in the jQuery set you call it on. It doesn't just give you one element's parent like the `parentNode` or `parentElement` properties would (if you didn't use them in a loop).
2. Because you can pass it an optional selector so that if the parent doesn't match the selector, you get back an empty set.
3. Because it returns a jQuery set, not a raw element like you'd get from `parentNode` or `parentElement`. That means you can call jQuery methods on it, as [Anuraag Vaidya points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837348/157247).

Consider this code:

```js
// Find `.a` elements
const a = $(".a");

// Find their parent elements
const parents = a.parent();
console.log(parents.length); // 2

// Find only their parent elements that match `.b`
const bParents = a.parent(".b");
console.log(bParents.length); // 1
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="a"></div>
</div>
<div class="b">
    <div class="a"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can see the set-based nature of jQuery working in the first `parent()` call, which returned a set of two elements (because each `.a` element is in its own parent).

You can see the filtering nature of it in the second result, since only one of the parent elements matched `.b`.

---

Just FWIW, I don't find [`parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) very useful. [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) is more useful for the places I need something like it, and [`parents`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) (plural) is useful when I need the ancestry of an element.

Comment: I missed the selector to the parent() part. Good one.

Comment: I second the thing about `.closest()`. Obviously different, but I've used `.parent()` so little I didn't know either of those points (explicitly)...

Comment: The takeaway is, sometimes you _don't_ need `.closest()`.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery has traditionally provided methods that you can chain in order to perform various operations within a single line of code without having to use bunch of variables.

Let's take a simple example.
If you have an element and you want to add 'red' class to the parent,'blue' class to its parent's parent, and then get the children of the original element's grand parent, you could write:

`$('yourObject').parent().addClass('red').parent().addClass('blue').children()`

To do this in plain JS, you would have to write much more:

```
let yourElement = <yourElementHere>;
yourElement.parentNode.setAttribute('class',yourElement.parentNode.getAttribute('class') + ' red');
yourElement.parentNode.parentNode.setAttribute('class',yourElement.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('class') + ' blue');
let uncles = yourElement.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes;
```

You're able to shorten your code quite a bit using `parent()` function by placing it in a call chain.

Answer (score 1):

It is among other things very useful when you do NOT know the parent - especially when delegating

I personally prefer [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) which also has found its way into [vanilla JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```js
$(function() {
  $("nav a").on("click",function(e) { // any "a" in nav
    e.preventDefault();
    const $parent = $(this).parent(); // $(this).closest("li")
    const $grandParent = $(this).parent().parent(); // $(this).closest("ul");
    $parent.toggleClass("active"); // toggle the containing li
    $grandParent.toggleClass("activeUL",
       $grandParent.find(".active").length>0 // if any active change the UL
    ); 
  })
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow
}

.activeUL {
  background-color: grey
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Click</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Click</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Click</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Click</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Click</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Click</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Click</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Click</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is why this function is there when we can select the parent element directly.

You are presuming that you know exactly which unique (child) element you're holding, and therefore should know the exact parent element it has. But that's not a given.

Suppose I add the same click event handler to three wildly different elements (of the same class), in completely different parts of the DOM:

```
<div id="parent1">
    <span id="child1" class="clickme" />
    <div id="parent2">
        <span id="child2" class="clickme" />
    </div>
    <ul>
       <li id="parent3">
          <a href="#" id="child3" class="clickme" />
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've labeled the children and parents so you can clearly see that even though there are three different element with the same class, they each have a different parent.

Now consider the following click event:

```
$(".clickme").click(function() {
    alert("the parent id of the clicked element is " + ???);
});
```

Focus on the `???`, how would you be able to find the correct parent element?

How would this click handler be able to know what the exact parent is, since it could be one of three elements (and thus one of three parents)?

If all you know is the child (`$(this)`), then you ask the child who its parent is. That is exactly what `$(this).parent()` does.

```
$(".clickme").click(function() {
    var parentId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    alert("the parent id of the clicked element is " + parentId);
});
```

Comment: You could accomplish this with `this.parentNode.id`. Am I not understanding?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: The focus of the question and this answer isn't on finding alternatives to `parent()`, it's about explaining its purpose. OP's premise is that you always know the exact child and therefore the exact parent, which isn't the case, and thus what I'm addressing in this answer. Yes, for accessing the id of an element you don't _have_ to use jQuery, but you're getting distracted by the simplified example I'm using instead of the  gist of the answer.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: `parentNode` also doesn't return a jQuery element, and if this parent-finding logic in one step in a larger chain of operations, repeatedly toggling between jQuery objects and non-jQuery objects is going to be a hassle.

Comment: The way the answer is phrased it sounds like jQuery's special trick is giving a wrapped `.parentNode` element, such that that is the only way to get the parent's `id`? That's not much of a party trick for jQuery. Facially, stating that jQuery does something you don't need jQuery for doesn't seem to make a strong argument. No downvote, I just don't get it is all.

Comment: I see @JaredFarrish 's point in the way the example code was written, so I've taken the liberty of rephrasing the example slightly so the emphasis is on .parent() not .parent().id

Comment: First, I would not have edited the answer. Second, I can say since I've been using it when it was beta software, it's a sense-making layer for abstracting the cruft of the DOM methods that existed circa 2007. I mean, you use to have to get an ActiveX object to do the newly-named "AJAX" stuff. It sucked. Third, it's a node traversal compositor, so the jQuery object with context is the power and the point itself. That's why i don't see the value of getting `this.parentNode` properties per se, `jQuery().parent()` fills an expressive gap, really no more no less. You make some good points, though.